# Loop through multiple dictionaries

Tags: c#, dictionary, foreach

I have 6 dictionaries. I want to compare another dictionaries against each one of them and see what dictionaries contains what strings. Is it possible to do with a foreach loop?

```
static Dictionary<string, int> d = new Dictionary<string, int>();
static Dictionary<string, double> dNL = new Dictionary<string, double>();
static Dictionary<string, double> dDE = new Dictionary<string, double>();
static Dictionary<string, double> dFR = new Dictionary<string, double>();
static Dictionary<string, double> dSP = new Dictionary<string, double>();
static Dictionary<string, double> dEN = new Dictionary<string, double>();
static Dictionary<string, double> dIT = new Dictionary<string, double>();

foreach (var f in d)
{
    if (dNL.ContainsKey(f.Key))
    {
        //add to a numeric?
    }
    if (dDE.ContainsKey(f.Key))
    {
        //add to a numeric?
    }
}
```

something like this?

what I currently have (and not working like intended):

```
// need to find a better solution
foreach (var f in d)
{
    if (dNL.ContainsKey(f.Key))
    {
        dNLtotaal++;
    }
}
foreach (var f in d)
{
    if (dDE.ContainsKey(f.Key))
    {
        dDEtotaal++;
    }
}
foreach (var f in d)
{
    if (dFR.ContainsKey(f.Key))
    {
        dFRtotaal++;
    }
}
foreach (var f in d)
{
    if (dSP.ContainsKey(f.Key))
    {
        dSPtotaal++;
    }
}
foreach (var f in d)
{
    if (dEN.ContainsKey(f.Key))
    {
        dENtotaal++;
    }
}
foreach (var f in d)
{
    if (dIT.ContainsKey(f.Key))
    {
        dITtotaal++;
    }
}
// NEED A MUCH BETTER SOLUTION
List<int> totaleD = new List<int>();
totaleD.Add(dNLtotaal);
totaleD.Add(dDEtotaal);
totaleD.Add(dFRtotaal);
totaleD.Add(dSPtotaal);
totaleD.Add(dENtotaal);
totaleD.Add(dITtotaal);
int max = !totaleD.Any() ? -1 : totaleD.Select((value, index) => new { Value = value, Index = index }).Aggregate((a, b) => (a.Value > b.Value) ? a : b).Index;
var maxIndex = totaleD.IndexOf(totaleD.Max());
Console.WriteLine(maxIndex);
```

Comment: you can shorten it with lambda , I cant give an example on this moment, sorry

Comment: Can you explain what your last line is supposed to do? Is it supposed to tell you which dictionary has the most matches?

Comment: How exactly is your code not working as intended?

Comment: You can combine all those `foreach` statements into one that just has each `if` statement inside of it and you can loop over the `Keys` of `d` instead.

Comment: @Rob yes, I'm trying to get the dictionary which has the most matches to it, but I talked with a friend and I found the problem for this problem. I'm counting how many keys are in the dictionary, but every dictionary has 1 or 0 keys containing that bigram. for instance; he is only present 1 time in every dictionary, so every int has a value of 1.

Comment: @juharr it was a mistake which flew right over my head. In each dictionary the string is only present 0 or 1 times.

Comment: @Remco1250 I'm not sure I understand.  You're taking each key in `d` and check for it in each of the other dictionary and counting how many common keys there are.  It is true that a specific key can only be in a dictionary once, but you're counting how many of the keys in one are in a set of others which can result in counts higher than 1.

Comment: @juharr Yep you're right. I'm totally confused at the moment. I pushed this problem aside for a moment and focus my attention on another problem I currently have, but I can use the answers from this question as well. Could you elaborate your comment about the foreach statement with each if inside it? Isn't it true that if i put one bigram in it only one if will start? even though in 5 out of 6 dictionaries the bigram is present?

Comment: @Remco1250 Only if you do `else if`.  If you just have a bunch of `if` statements in a row it will run each one.

Comment: @juharr so I could do it as in the first block of code? foreach(){if() if() if()}?

Comment: @Remco1250 Exactly, but Rob has a nice answer that compacts all your code if you feel comfortable with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var items = d.Keys;
var dictionaries = new[] { dNL, dDE, dFR, dSP, dEN, dIT };
var result = dictionaries.Select((d, index) =>
    new {
        Index = index,
        Matches = items.Count(i => d.ContainsKey(i))
    })
    .OrderByDescending(i => i.Matches)
    .Select(i => i.Index)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Which gives you the index of the dictionary with the most matches

Comment: I assume that `items` is suppose to be `d.Keys`.

Comment: @juharr Yes - sorry, I missed the declaration of `d` and assumed it to be a `List<string>`. Thanks for the catch

Answer (score 0):

You could use lambda expressions to get the desired results. In following example, I tried to use two dictionaries:

```
int dNLtotaal = 0;
Dictionary<string, double> dNL = new Dictionary<string, double>();
Dictionary<string, double> dDE = new Dictionary<string, double>();

dNL.Keys.Where(k => dDE.ContainsKey(k)).ToList().ForEach(k => dNLtotaal++);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Instead of using `ToList` and `Foreach` you can just use `Count` and assign the result to `dNLtotal`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to have 1 Dictionary instead of 6? And keep there a pair [string, List[SomeObject]] where SomeObject is a class like

```
class SomeObject
{
    public Enum Type;//dNL, dDE etc
    public double Value;
}
```